# Do you know any Slide-Menu (like the example) in vertical?

Tags: html, css, menu

For the mobile version, I have to have a vertical menu. Knowing that for the computer version I use this one (the example), I'd like to know if someone has any CodePen (or other) for what I want?

Otherwise, can I adapt it myself? Only by swapping the vertical value with the horizontal one?

The example (https://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/XbbdZJ):

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}


.slide-toggle{
  display: none;
}

.slidemenu{
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidemenu label{
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.2;

}

.slidemenu label:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
}

.slidemenu label span{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;    
}

.slidemenu label .icon{
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 2px #333;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/*Bar Style*/

.slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider .bar{
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*Animations*/
.slidemenu label, .slider .bar {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

/*Toggle*/

.slidemenu .slide-toggle:checked + label{
  opacity: 1;
}



.slidemenu #slide-item-1:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 0; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-2:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 25%; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-3:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 50%; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-4:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 75%; }
```

```html
<nav class="slidemenu">
  
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <input type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-1" class="slide-toggle" checked/>
  <label for="slide-item-1"><p class="icon">♬</p><span>Home</span></label>
  
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <input type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-2" class="slide-toggle"/>
  <label for="slide-item-2"><p class="icon">★</p><span>About</span></label>
  
  <!-- Item 3 -->
  <input type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-3" class="slide-toggle"/>
  <label for="slide-item-3"><p class="icon">✈</p><span>Folio</span></label>
  
  <!-- Item 4 -->
  <input type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-4" class="slide-toggle"/>
  <label for="slide-item-4"><p class="icon">✎</p><span>Blog</span></label>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <!-- Bar -->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used media queries.You can adjust according to your need.When you reduce the size of the page, it will rotate 90 degrees.

https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/RwWgxpj

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}


.slide-toggle{
  display: none;
}

.slidemenu{
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidemenu label{
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.2;

}

@media all and (max-width:1081px){
  .slidemenu {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 700px;

    padding: 250px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90.0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90.0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90.0deg);
}

.slidemenu label{
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);

}

}



.slidemenu label:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
}

.slidemenu label span{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;    
}

.slidemenu label .icon{
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 2px #333;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/*Bar Style*/

.slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider .bar{
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*Animations*/
.slidemenu label, .slider .bar {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

/*Toggle*/

.slidemenu .slide-toggle:checked + label{
  opacity: 1;
}



.slidemenu #slide-item-1:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 0; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-2:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 25%; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-3:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 50%; }
.slidemenu #slide-item-4:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 75%; }
```